# Can Django-Rest-Framework create an API that returns a single attribute of an Object Model instance?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

In my Django app, I have the following Models:

```
class MyModelA(models.Model):  
    myAttributeA = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class MyModelB(models.Model):
    myParent = models.OneToOneField(myModelA)  
    myAttributeB = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

My settings.py has the following Rest Permission settings:

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly',),
```

I also have the following Serializers:

```
class MyModelASerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
    model = MyModelA
    fields = ('myAttributeA',)

class MyModelBSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
    model = MyModelB
    fields = ('myParent', 'myAttributeB',)
```

Now I want to write a simple Django-Rest-Framework API that will allow any user (weather authenticated or not) to retrieve the value of myParent on any instance of MyModelB assuming they have the Primary Key of the MyModelB instance. This should be rather simple. I'm not trying to update, create, or delete anything. I just want to retrieve the value of one attribute of the instance. But I also want my urls.py to match this endpoint to the API:

```
url(r'^api/AttrMyModelA/(?P<myModelAID>\d+)/?$', SOMETHING HERE. NOT SURE WHAT)
```

However, I cannot figure out which pattern to use from the tutorial to make this work. Should I use function based or class based views? Should I use Generic API views? Do I need a decorator or no? Mixins? Can someone please show me what my view should look like and what the urls.py endpoint should look like?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You require a `RetrieveAPIView`-derived class to tie things together:

```
class MyModelAView(RetrieveAPIView):
    model = MyModelA
    serializer_class = MyModelASerializer
```

The route mentioned by you would then look like this:

```
url(r'^api/AttrMyModelA/(?P<pk>\d+)/?$', MyModelAView.as_view())
```

Note that `pk` is the default look-up field used by APIView-derived classes when performing single object queries.

You have defined a default permission class (in `settings.py`), so unless you want to override that you don't need to specify a `permission_classes` value in your view class.

Comment: Thanks, from what I understand the default permission setting I have specified will allow unauthenticated reads, but not writes to my model objects. So that should be ok, right? I am careful to not put any code in the GET requests that might modify my database.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. `RetrieveAPIView` only provides a `get()` method implementation, which services HTTP GET requests and provides the expected *read-only* semantics that you desire.

Comment: It's probably worth also pointing out that permission classes on their own have no direct bearing on whether objects are read-only, or otherwise. Permission classes allow you to specify whether end-points (and therefore objects) may be accessed. Whether you grant permission to read, write, etc is up to you.

Comment: @saqibAli Does this not answer your question? If not, then it would be useful to know that.

Comment: It works perfectly!! My apologies for not marking it correct earlier. I swear it was on my list of things to do for today -- even before you reminded me. Thank you.